# PHP files cached with Yii command

Tags: php, yii

I have an application based on Yii, in which, I developed a command.

The problem is that when editing certain PHP files, they are not being updated.

If you edit the command controller, the changes are assumed immediately, but if you edit a file that is called from the command controller, which is in another folder, they are not.

The only thing that works is to restart Docker.

Some notes:

- I've already checked that I don't have Opcache installed.
- When I'm inside the docker, in the folder where the file is, the file is updated with what I edited.
- I have already executed the `cache / flush-all` command from yii before executing the command again, and continue to display the first result.

Can anyone help me realize the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what was my problem.

It was about [the mounted volumes configuration](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs-caching/) that I had, in my docker-composer.yml file.

I was using cached, but for my case consistent was more appropriate, to always get an exact copy of the files that I have on the host.

Another possibility, that it worked with success for me, was to update the IDE settings, in my case PHPStorm, to not use "Safe write".